# How to get a selected star value using Rateit JQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JQuery.I'm using Jquery Rateit plugin for rating,I installed the NuGet package.Now all I want is to get the value of the selected star.With the help of google I tried this way but I didn't make.Here is the code I tried.

```
 <span id="RateForm_15" class="rateit"></span>
<script>
var rateValue = $('#RateForm_15 > div').attr('aria-valuenow');
</script>
```

Could anyone please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Amazing things happen when you allocate time to [read the docs](http://gjunge.github.io/rateit.js/examples/#ex_9)

Comment: Thanq you very much it helped  me a lot....